# Linked hover between elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent

How can I use d3 to retrieve and use a title attribute of a non-svg DOM element?

In this D3 example I'm working on, when a user hovers over a focus country the corresponding title box goes to hover state as well:

http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/6967409

However, when I tried to repeat it the other way (change the state of the correct country when hovering the title box), I get "Cannot read property of undefined." I've tried to define it a few dozen ways at this point and it's just not returning the country name values. The problem seems to originate from this line:

```
b.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  d3.selectAll("[title=" + d.title + "]").classed("countryActive",true);
});
```

where "b" is every title box:

```
b = d3.selectAll(".mminfo");
```

I'd be psyched if anyone can point out what must be a pretty basic syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the data bound to the elements (through `d`) without having bound elements. That is, `d` is not defined because you're creating the `.mminfo` elements manually, without using the D3 `.data().enter()` pattern.

The title is in the attributes of those elements though, so all you need to change is `d.title` to `this.title`. Working example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/6990939).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I love it when the real problem is a basic failure of my understanding of javascript :)

Comment: This is more of a D3 issue than Javascript in general. Technically, the callbacks for D3 selections expect the elements to have `.__data__` members, which is what will be passed to the callback function (`d` in your example). If `.__data__` is undefined, so is `d`.